# handle the form data using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport-local

Here is my simple form.html :

```html
<form id="login-form" action=" ?? " method="post">Email
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="Email" id="em" />
    <br/>password
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="password" id="pas" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Here is my express node.js code app.js:

```js
app.post('/form', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    failureFlash: true // allow flash messages
}),

function (req, res) {
    console.log("hello");

    if (req.body.remember) {
        req.session.cookie.maxAge = 1000 * 60 * 3;
    } else {
        req.session.cookie.expires = false;
    }
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

When I wrote app.js path "our-project/app.js" in the action attribute and submited the form there is no any response.
the form.html path "our-project/form/form.html"

Comment: you need to use the page's external url instead. In your case, it is "/form"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to what was written in the comments section:

The action part of the html form is a little bit unclear what it means is:
I will make action to this specific URL path.

For example if you want to GET data from the path "/path" you would type
        
Literally when you use get it changes the path on the URL like:
facebook.com/user=id&name=zargold.

Or if you wanted it to POST to that specific path... it will:
         
Using the POST it will take that information... 
then I would probably use the npm module body-parser *so you can easily parse the information coming from the body and extract as body.name or body.email.